# Rails form with dynamic test bank

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to create a question bank where the test creator can specify the number of question they would like to see for each category of the form.

Currently I loop through all of the question to build the form, and I'm not sure how to simply pull out only x number of questions per category.

```
@questions = AuditQuestions.where(question_active: 'Y', audit_forms_id: session[:audit_forms_id]).order(question_order_number: :asc)
```

Table structure:

```
id audit_forms_id question_category question_title question_text question_order_number question_active
```

Comment: do you want the first x questions (in the DB) per category ?

Comment: Looking for random x per category. I wrote an SQL query to return what I want, buy ran into the issue rails not wanting multiple statements in a single query.